# How to build .air file through Adt.jar with the help of NativeProcess in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>       
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var nativeProcess:NativeProcess;

        private function onGo() : void {
            outputField.text = "";

            var file:File = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_18\\bin\\java.exe");
            var descriptorFile:File = new File("C:\\AirPackageApp-app.xml");
            var swfFile:File = new File("C:\\AirPackageApp.swf");
            var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
            processArgs.push("-jar");
            processArgs.push("C:\\adt.jar");
            processArgs.push("-checkstore");
            processArgs.push("-storetype");
            processArgs.push("pkcs12");
            processArgs.push("-keystore");
            processArgs.push("-storepass");
            processArgs.push("sybrant"); 
            processArgs.push("c:\\nodename.air");           
            processArgs.push(descriptorFile.nativePath);           
            processArgs.push(swfFile.nativePath);           

            var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

            nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
            nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onCertErrOutputData);
            nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA,onCertOutputData);
            nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
        }

        private function onCertErrOutputData(event:ProgressEvent) : void {
            var certResponse:String = new String();
            certResponse = nativeProcess.standardError.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardError.bytesAvailable);
            trace(certResponse);
            outputField.text += certResponse;   
            if ( certResponse.substr(0,5) == "valid") {
                trace("Correct password!");
                nativeProcess.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onCertOutputData);
                nativeProcess.exit();
            } else {
                trace("Incorrect password! Error...");
                nativeProcess.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onCertOutputData);
                nativeProcess.exit();
            }
        }

        protected function onCertOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace(nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<s:Button label="go" click="onGo()" />
<s:TextInput id="passField"/>
<s:TextArea id="outputField" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

It works everything fine when working with command prompt.It generate nodename.air file in C:\nodename.air. But when using native process it works upto following arguments

```
  processArgs.push("-storepass");
 processArgs.push("sybrant");
```

After that if i missspelled my air-descriptor.xml file or my swf file it doesn't throw any error msg but it throws error in command prompt.(OS Windows 7, Java version 1.6)

Thanks,
Raja.J

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This class might helpful for you
air_command.bat
java -jar adt.jar -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore  keyfile.p12 -storepass mypassword SampleApp.air SampleApp-app.xml SampleApp.swf

Before run applications

- make sure java class path is set
- desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice exendedMobileDevice

to

extendedDesktop

```
    package
{
 import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
 import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
 import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
 import flash.filesystem.File;

 import mx.controls.Alert;

public class PlatformPackaging
 {
 private var nativeProcess:NativeProcess;
 private var isErrorOccured:Boolean;

 private var batFile:File;
 private var cmdFile:File;

 private function get isWindows():Boolean
 {
 return true;
 }

 public function PlatformPackaging()
 {
 }

 public function start(targetPlatform:String):void
 {
 if(isWindows)
 {
 if(targetPlatform == TargetPlatform.APPLE_IPA)
 {
 batFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/ipa_command.bat");
 cmdFile = new File("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
 }
 else if(targetPlatform == TargetPlatform.WINDOWS_AIR)
 {
 batFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/air_command.bat");
 cmdFile = new File("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
 }
 else if(targetPlatform == TargetPlatform.ANDROID_APK)
 {
 batFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/apk_command.bat");
 cmdFile = new File("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
 }
 }

 proceedToPackaging();

 }

 private function proceedToPackaging():void {

 var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;

 processArgs.push("/c");
 processArgs.push(batFile.nativePath);

 var workingDirectory:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/");
 var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

 nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
 nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = cmdFile;
 nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = workingDirectory;

 nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
 nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onStandardErrorOutputDataHandler);
 nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA,onStandardOutputDataHandler);
 nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
 }

 private function onStandardErrorOutputDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent) : void
 {
 var certResponse:String = nativeProcess.standardError.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardError.bytesAvailable);

 trace(certResponse);
 nativeProcess.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onStandardOutputDataHandler);
 nativeProcess.exit();
 }

 Alert.show(certResponse,'Error');
 }

 protected function onStandardOutputDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
 {
 var status:String = nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);

 Alert.show(status)
 }

 }
}
```