# AS3 - NativeProcess that uses additional file

Tags: actionscript-3, process, air

So I have an AIR app that runs an simple command-line program. The program basically takes in a file, decompresses it, and outputs the results. The only arguments I can give it are the input file, and it automatically outputs the results in the folder it's in. Naturally, I'm running the program using the `NativeProcess` class, which in turn needs a `NativeProcessStartupInfo` object to start.

Anyway, the `NativeProcessStartupInfo`'s `workingDirectory` property is set to the folder of the file I'm going to put into the program, so that the decompressed results are put into that folder. However, the thing is that the program requires an additional file (a .dat) in the same directory as it to run. Which means that wherever `workingDirectory` is, that .dat needs to be there as well.

For the time being, I'm copying over the .dat and deleting it after the decompression is done. I was wondering though if there's a better way to do this? Is there a value in `NativeProcess` or `NativeProcessStartupInfo` that can help that I don't know about?

Comment: Please check out link it will help you bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817875/how-to-build-air-file-through-adt-jar-with-the-help-of-nativeprocess-in-adobe-a

Comment: @Raja: Sorry, but I can't see how that question helps me. It seems like an unrelated problem.